# How do i add seperate error bars for a column plot displaying means in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, errorbar

Let's say my data frame was created like this:

```
df=data.frame(type=as.factor(c("tree","tree","tree","tree", "bush","bush","bush", "bush","flower", "flower", "flower", "flower")),
              age=as.factor(c(5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1)),
              size=c(11,3,16,5,2,0.5,3,0.4,1,0.2,0.9,0.15))
```

and now it looks like that:

```
> df
     type age  size
1    tree   5 11.00
2    tree   1  3.00
3    tree   5 16.00
4    tree   1  5.00
5    bush   5  2.00
6    bush   1  0.50
7    bush   5  3.00
8    bush   1  0.40
9  flower   5  1.00
10 flower   1  0.20
11 flower   5  0.90
12 flower   1  0.15
```

I want my x axis to compare the age factor 5 and 1, while having the type factor next to each other.

```
plot = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = age, y = size, fill=type))
plot = plot + geom_col(position = "dodge")
plot
```

[so far so good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WA2y.jpg)

Now I'm really struggling with applying sensibles error bars to my columns using `geom_errorbar()`. They were supposed to display the standard deviation for each column

Comment: What do you mean by "standard deviation for each column"?

Comment: the standard deviation for the size of five year old trees, five year old bushes and so on. For example mean +- standard deviation of 5 year old trees as the error bar borders for that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind? where the error bar represents plus and minus one standard deviation from the mean?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(type=as.factor(c("tree","tree","tree","tree", "bush","bush","bush", "bush","flower", "flower", "flower", "flower")),
              age=as.factor(c(5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1,5,1)),
              size=c(11,3,16,5,2,0.5,3,0.4,1,0.2,0.9,0.15))

df2 <- 
  df1 |> 
  group_by(type, age) |> 
  summarise(sd = sd(size),
            mean_size = mean(size), .groups = "drop") |> 
  mutate(sd_min = mean_size - sd,
         sd_max = mean_size + sd)

ggplot(df2, aes(age, mean_size, fill = type))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = sd_min, ymax = sd_max), position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: that is exactly what i had in mind! Thanks a lot